# How to optimize mp4 video for playback as smooth as possible in browser (HTML5)

Tags: optimization, html5-video, mp4

Do you know any tools that help you optimize mp4 video so it plays smoothly even on older devices (when running as a background of html5 page).

Thanks for all the tips!

Best

Comment: Good info on that: http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to reduce the bitrate of the video itself.  This will decrease the likelihood that the video player has to stop and buffer, and decreases the amount of data the video player has to process in realtime.

There's a lot of good data in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/4244/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-huge-mp4-video), but the short version is to run it through `ffmpeg` like this, replacing 1000000 with the appropriate value for your video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 1000000 output.mp4
```

More info in [this comment](https://superuser.com/a/4252).

Comment: If making the video for web use you should also include the faststart flag (moves the moov atom to the start of the video so the browser can start playback instantly) `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 1000000 -movflags faststart output.mp4`